# Suppress the number of the first verse(s) of a chapter in the text body but not in the header

Tags: header-footer

In the following example, how can I suppress the number of the first verse (or verses such as 1-2) of a Bible chapter in the text body without suppressing it in the headers? (This is based on material found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377505/force-superscript-to-stay-specified-distance-before-following-word-without-mbox).)

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% headers
\makeoddhead{headings}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\leftmark}

%remove the marks set by \section.
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{%
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{}
}

%%%%chapter format
\newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
\newcommand{\gnumChapters}{0}

\newcommand{\gChapter}[1]{\lettrine[lines=2,nindent=.5em,findent=0em]{{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\gnumChapters}{#1}}

%%%%verse format
\makeatletter
% define a 'smaller textsuperscript' macro
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsmallsuperscript[1]{%
\@textsmallsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
\def\@textsmallsuperscript#1{%
{\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\ssf@size\z@#1}}}}}
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\gverse}[1]{{\textsmallsuperscript{#1}\hspace*{.1em}\ignorespaces\markboth{\chaplabel\ \gnumChapters:#1}{\chaplabel\gnumChapters:#1}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\gChapter{1}
\gverse{1-2}\lipsum[2]
\gverse{3}\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to set a flag in the `\gchapter` macro, and then test to detect the first use of `\gverse` after `\gchapter`.

Note, resetting the flag is done *outside* your doubled `{{...}}` in `\gverse`, otherwise it only affects a local copy of the flag, which doesn't work!

```
    ...
    %%%%chapter format
    \newcommand{\chaplabel}{}
    \newcommand{\gnumChapters}{0}
    \newif\ifshowverseno

    \newcommand{\gChapter}[1]{\showversenofalse\lettrine[lines=2,nindent=.5em,findent=0em]{{\textcolor{black}{#1}}}{}\markboth{\chaplabel\ #1:1}{\chaplabel\ #1:1}\renewcommand{\gnumChapters}{#1}}

    %%%%verse format
    \makeatletter
    % define a 'smaller textsuperscript' macro
    \DeclareRobustCommand*\textsmallsuperscript[1]{%
    \@textsmallsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
    \def\@textsmallsuperscript#1{%
    {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\ssf@size\z@#1}}}}}
    \makeatletter

    \newcommand{\gverse}[1]{{\ifshowverseno\textsmallsuperscript{#1}\hspace*{.1em}\ignorespaces \fi%
       \markboth{\chaplabel\ \gnumChapters:#1}{\chaplabel\gnumChapters:#1}}\showversenotrue\ignorespaces}

    \begin{document}
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: %alephzero What about the following scenario: The verse should be suppressed unless gverse is more than one verse, eg \gverse{1-2}. In this case it should be shown to avoid confusion (I am aware of the fact that stylistically this questionable, but an Asian reader would tend to think that there is a verse missing if the first numbered verse begins with 3).

Comment: A hack is to just add \gverse{1-2} again after \gverse{1-2}. That's not very elegant, but it works.