# Title with the header in critical edition

Tags: fancyhdr, reledmac

i'am a newbie and this is my first question about latex!
I would like to know if it was possible to create, in a critical edition, a sort of chapter counter, sections etc. of the text and print them in fancyhdr. I do not know I was clear.
The closest thing I found is the solution of *user35641* [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129843/trouble-with-bible-style-page-header-lines/214630), but the problem is that the header is printed over the width of the text in a page layout of 15cm (width) and 23cm (height) in book class.

Thank you

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepacakge[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[noeledmac]{ledmac} % I know it is obsolete package but, for me, it's working well

\footparagraph{A} % textual variants of apparatus in paragraph

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering % begin line numeration

\pstart

\begin{center}
LIBER I % I would like this to be the first counter to print in fancyhdr

\end{center}


1. %(second type of counter, i.e "chapter")


 Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text


1.1  %(third type of counter, i.e "section")

Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Example of  what I mean (not the actual result of compiling)
[image]

Original [link image](http://www.fluxus-virus.com/img/testpo2-petit.gif)

I think i found the way

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepacakge[latin]{babel} 

\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % self explaining
\usepackage{reledmac}
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer} % thanks to djdekker.net
\newcounter{libro}% book
\newcounter{capitolo} %chapter bold
\newcounter{sezione} %section  italic
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L,R]{}% reset header
\fancyhead[CO,CE]{\thelibro. \thecapitolo-\thesezione}

 \begin{center}
  % number of book in normal text
 \end{center}
 \beginnumbering
 \pstart

\refstepcounter{libro} % book reference

 \ledsidenote{\textbf{X}} \refstepcounter{capitolo}  Text
 Text

 \ledsidenote{\texit{X}} \refstepcounter{sezione} Text Text  

 \pend

 \endnumbering

 \end{document}
```

In other words: i create three counters (libro, capitolo, sezione). 
I print a ledsidenote bold if capitolo (so \refstrepcounter{capitolo})
 if sezione italic (so \refstepcounter{sezione})

The problem is: the ledsidenote sezione 3 is on page 2  but the header print it even onpage 1. The header is "static"; it doesn't print the actual capitolo/ sezione of the actual page.

Any solutions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What do you mean by "critical edition"? By the way, you should provide a minimal working example showing what you have tried, as well as a sketch or a clear description showing what you want -- all that help us a lot!

Comment: Sorry, in my country the closest translation is "Critical Edition". I think it is more understandable to use "scholarly edition" or those texts that show the textual variations of the manuscripts like the Novum Testamentum Graece.

Comment: ‘Critical edition’ is indeed the name for this in English. If you read French, you’ll be interested in http://geekographie.maieul.net/225

Comment: @Thérèse  I already know that book but i didn't find the solution. Thak you anyway!

Comment: I think the most problematic thing is your title, which is not very explicit, and make JouleV asking for it. Indeed, now, you already make critical edition. The most important thing in your question is "title with the header in critical edition".  I will answer about your problem soon.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, first I will try to resume your need, as you did't be very explicit.

1. You need to typeset critical edition. Perfect, that is why ledmac and its successor is made for
2. In your critical edition, you need to add as ruling header

   1. The chapter number
   2. The starting and ending verse number, depending of the current page
      To manage header, you need `fancyhdr`, that is perfect.

The problem is double

1. To get the correct mark in you header (problem with `fancyhdr` )
2. To manage it with (re)ledmac (problem connex).

## Chapter and verse number in the header

So, starting with `fancyhdr`. As you may have read, or you should have read, running header work with marks system:

Two commands to be called in the text

- `\markboth{<l>}{<r>}`
- `\markright{<r>}`

Two commands to be called in the header

- `\leftmark` gives you the value of the `<l>` of the immediatly previous `markboth`
- `\rightmark` gives you the value of the `<r>` of the first `\markright` or `\markboth` of the current page, or the last `\markright` or `\markboth` of the previous page.

The problem, in your case, is that you need to deal with 3 marks

- chapter
- starting verse
- ending verse

I think, indeed, that there is some packages which will allow to have more mark. But, for the present case, we will simplify the example, and will consider that you start a  chapter with page break.

I will simplify the example, to have only two levels of numbering. We could look for complexer problem later, when you will have understood the mechanism of mark.

So a simplified example would be

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{reledmac} % Really, use reledmac, not ledmac
\pagestyle{fancy}%Calling fancy style
\fancyhead[L,R]{}%Reset header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%Page number in foot

\fancyhead[C]{\theliber, \rightmark-\leftmark}% In the center, print liber number + division
\newcounter{liber}%a spectific counter for liber


\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\markboth{#1}{#1}}%uste a shortup for divison
\begin{document}


\newpage
\refstepcounter{liber}
\begin{center}
    LIBER \theliber
\end{center}

\division{1} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text


\division{2} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\newpage % Juste for the example
s

\division{3}
s

\division{4}
s

\newpage
\refstepcounter{liber}
\begin{center}
    LIBER \theliber
\end{center}

\division{1} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text


\division{2} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\newpage % Juste for the example
s

\division{3}
s

\division{4}
s

\end{document}
```

I am not at all a specialist of `\mark`, and I think you  could need more complex case to manage. But my point is that, this problem, is not directly related with `ledmac`. You just need to explain clearly what type of divisions you need in your header, and the fact that you need ranges.

## Now, dealing with ledmac

First of all, I am sorry to tell you that you will need to switch to reledmac. Why ? because dealing with `\mark` is not possible directly in ledmac, and that you will need feature from reledmac.

Here, a basic rule to be remembered with `ledmac`: between `\pstart`...`\pend`, do not use:

- size font change
- justification modification
- marking command.

So, how to deal

1. You `center` environnement could be used inside a optional argument of `\pstart`
2. You can use `\doinsidethislinehook` to incluse sentive command like `\marking`. Look at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/reledmac/examples/2-subdivision-number-in-header.tex for an example

So, here an adapted code for reledmac

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[latin]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{reledmac} % Really, use reledmac, not ledmac
\pagestyle{fancy}%Calling fancy style
\fancyhead[L,R]{}%Reset header
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%Page number in foot

\fancyhead[C]{\theliber, \rightmark-\leftmark}% In the center, print liber number + division
\newcounter{liber}%a spectific counter for liber


\newcommand{\division}[1]{#1.\doinsidethislinehook{\markboth{#1}{#1}}}%uste a shortup for divison
\begin{document}


\beginnumbering
\pstart[\newpage
\refstepcounter{liber}
\begin{center}
    LIBER \theliber
\end{center}]
\division{1} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\pstart
\division{2} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\newpage % Juste for the example
\pstart
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{3}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{4}
s
\pend
\newpage
\pstart[
\refstepcounter{liber}
\begin{center}
    LIBER \theliber
\end{center}
]
\division{1} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\pstart
\division{2} Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text Dummy text
\pend
\newpage % Juste for the example
\pstart
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{3}
s
\pend
\pstart
\division{4}
s
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

## Genral conclusion

1. First, think without reledmac
2. Then, adapt to reledmac