# How to reset chapters in biblie

Tags: pdftex, chapters

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,letterpaper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[inner=5cm,
                  outer=5cm,
                  marginparsep=8pt,
                  marginparwidth=40mm,
                  %showframe% for show your page design, normaly not used
                  ]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}     
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage[scaled=.50]{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{schemata}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{.5pt}

\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}%\textwidth
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000

\makeatletter
\newcommand\versenumcolor{red}
\newcommand\chapnumcolor{red}
\renewcommand\paragraph{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                {.25ex \@plus.25ex \@minus.1ex}%
                {-.5em}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{\versenumcolor}}}%\sffamily\normalfont
                
\newlength{\biblechapskip}
  \setlength{\biblechapskip}{1em plus .33em minus .2em}
\newcounter{biblechapter}
\newcounter{bibleverse}[biblechapter]
\renewcommand\chaptername{Book}
\let\ltx@chapter=\chapter
\let\ltx@paragraph=\paragraph
\newcommand{\book}[1]{%
  \gdef\currbook{#1}
  \ltx@chapter{#1}}
\newcount\biblechap@svdopt
\newenvironment{biblechapter}[1][\thebiblechapter]
  {\biblechap@svdopt=#1
  \ifnum\c@biblechapter=\biblechap@svdopt\else
    \advance\biblechap@svdopt by -1\fi
  \setcounter{biblechapter}{\the\biblechap@svdopt}
  \refstepcounter{biblechapter}
  \lettrine{\color{\chapnumcolor}\lower-5pt\hbox{\thebiblechapter}}{}\ignorespaces}
  {\vspace{\biblechapskip}}
\renewcommand{\verse}[1][\thebibleverse]{%
  \refstepcounter{bibleverse}
  \markright{{\scshape\currbook} \thebiblechapter:\thebibleverse}
  \ifnum\c@bibleverse=1\else
    \ltx@paragraph*{#1}\fi}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge}
\def\@marginparreset{%
  \reset@font
  \normalsize
  \@setminipage
}

\makeatletter
\def\@marginparreset{%
  \reset@font
  \small
  \@marginparfont
  \@setminipage
}
\def\@marginparfont{\normalfont} % \itshape or whatever
\makeatother


\title{La Santa Biblia}
\date{}
\author{}

%Variables
\input{var.tex}

%\Huge
%\huge
%\LARGE
%\Large
%\large
%\normalsize (default)
%\small
%\footnotesize
%\scriptsize
%\tiny
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\part*{El Antiguo Testamento}
  \setlength{\columnseprule}{.5pt}

\input{1.tex}
\input{2.tex}
\input{3.tex}
\input{4.tex}

\end{document}
```

And this is the structure for `1.tex`, `2.tex`, `3.tex` and so on. Just change the name of the book:

```
    \book{GÉNESIS}
\begin{center}\bigskip\par\textbf{La creación}\par\bigskip\end{center}
\begin{biblechapter} % GÉNESIS: 1
\verse %1
En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra.
\verse %2
Y la tierra estaba desordenada y vacía, y las tinieblas
estaban sobre la faz del abismo, y el Espíritu de Dios se
movía sobre la faz de las aguas.
\verse %3
Y dijo Dios: Sea la luz; y fue la luz.
\verse %4
Y vio Dios que la luz era buena; y separó Dios la luz de
las tinieblas.
\verse %5
Y llamó Dios a la luz Día, y a las tinieblas llamó Noche.
Y fue la tarde y la mañana un día.
\verse %6
Luego dijo Dios: Haya expansión en medio de las aguas, y
separe las aguas de las aguas.
\verse %7
E hizo Dios la expansión, y separó las aguas que estaban
debajo de la expansión, de las aguas que estaban sobre la
expansión. Y fue así.
\verse %8
Y llamó Dios a la expansión Cielos. Y fue la tarde y la
mañana el día segundo.
\verse %9
Dijo también Dios: Júntense las aguas que están debajo de
los cielos en un lugar, y descúbrase lo seco. Y fue así.
\verse %10
Y llamó Dios a lo seco Tierra, y a la reunión de las aguas
llamó Mares. Y vio Dios que era bueno.
\end{biblechapter}
\begin{biblechapter} % GÉNESIS: 2
\verse %1
Fueron, pues, acabados los cielos y la tierra, y todo el
ejército de ellos.
\verse %2
Y acabó Dios en el día séptimo la obra que hizo; y
reposó el día séptimo de toda la obra que hizo.
\verse %3
Y bendijo Dios al día séptimo, y lo santificó, porque en
él reposó de toda la obra que había hecho en la
creación.
\begin{center}\bigskip\par\textbf{El hombre en el huerto del Edén}\par\bigskip\end{center}
\verse %4
Estos son los orígenes de los cielos y de la tierra cuando
fueron creados, el día que Jehová Dios hizo la tierra y
los cielos,
\verse %5
y toda planta del campo antes que fuese en la tierra, y toda
hierba del campo antes que naciese; porque Jehová Dios aún
no había hecho llover sobre la tierra, ni había hombre
para que labrase la tierra,
\verse %6
sino que subía de la tierra un vapor, el cual regaba toda
la faz de la tierra.
\verse %7
Entonces Jehová Dios formó al hombre del polvo de la
tierra, y sopló en su nariz aliento de vida, y fue el
hombre un ser viviente.
\verse %8
Y Jehová Dios plantó un huerto en Edén, al oriente; y
puso allí al hombre que había formado.
\end{biblechapter}
```

Problem:

When change the book, I need to reset the chapter to one. And, in this point, don't know how to do it. After every book, continue counting the chapters, so in my example, Géenesis has 2 chapters, but in Exodus, continue en chapter 3, but what I need is Chapter 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Hi @Mensch do you have any comments about my question? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Elbert, welcome to TeX.SE! As you have your custom `\book` command, you could probably just `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` there. In general: to increase the probability of people wanting to engage with the problem, I would suggest you minimalize your example: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Are those geometry settings necessary for your problem? Or the 'ebgaramond' font? Headers? Footers? Margin notes? etc.